# dropping postMessage.. was from unexpected window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm running this file on a .html file on google scripts. I'm pretty much fetching data and returning it as options to the select. This code worked fine on my HTML but on google scripts html it does not return any data and gives me the error of `dropping postMessage.. was from unexpected window`

```js
    <select id="client_ID">

    </select>
  </div>
    <script>
      fetch('API').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        data.values.forEach(item => document.getElementById("client_ID").prepend(
          Object.assign(document.createElement("option"), {
            textContent: item[1],
            value: item[0]
          })
        ))
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log("Booo");
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't think that error is relevant. Check for other errors or debug to figure out the line it's erroring out.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But initially, I agree with @TheMaster's suggestion, you might want to debug your html in your browser console  to see if the fetching of your data is successful